# VBA Excel: Modulus for quarters

Tags: vba, excel, modulus

Please assist me in defining a modulus function for quarters: QuarterMod()

The function is to represent the quarter that you'll get when you take step a certain number of quarters in time.

Example:

Today, Juli 2013, we are at Q3.

What quarter will we be at a year from now? Well, todays quarter plus a year, i.e. `3 + 4`

```
Ans = QuarterMod(3 + 4)
Ans = 3
```

More examples:

```
QuarterMod(-1) = 3     
QuarterMod(0) = 4 
QuarterMod(1) = 1 
QuarterMod(2) = 2 
QuarterMod(3) = 3 
QuarterMod(4) = 4
QuarterMod(5) = 1
```

And so on.

Comment: what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: I'll add a clarification in the description

Comment: Just for fun: The same as an excel formula: `=CHOOSE(MOD(A1,4)+1,4,1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Public Function QuarterMod(Qtr As Integer)
   Dim i As Integer
   i = Qtr Mod 4
   If i <= 0 Then
      i = i + 4
   End If
   QuarterMod = i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this ? ...

```
Function QuarterMod(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
If n = 0 Then
  QuarterMod = 0
  Exit Function
End If
QuarterMod = n Mod 4
If QuarterMod = 0 Then QuarterMod = 4
If QuarterMod < 0 Then QuarterMod = QuarterMod + 4
End Function
```